# How to "uninstantiate" an object?

Tags: python, syntax

I wrote a function in Python:

```
def instantiate(c):
    if inspect.isclass(c): return c()
    elif isinstance(c, object): return c
    else: raise Exception, '%s is not an object or class.' % c
```

Now I want to do the opposite: get the class from an already instantiated object so that I can re-instantiate it with different parameters. How can I do that?

---

Tests:

```
>>> f = Form()
>>> type(f)()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: instance() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
>>> f.__class__()
<forms.Form instance at 0xb7f4d5cc>
```

More tests:

```
>>> o = object()
>>> type(o)()
<object object at 0xb7f78478>
>>> o.__class__()
<object object at 0xb7f78480>
```

Seems to work for `object` but not my `Form` class:

```
class Form:
    def __init__(self, data={}, prefix='', action='', id=None):
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with `self` but I don't know what.

Comment: Use `class Form(object):` to make a shiny beautiful new-style class, instead of the clunky old-style legacy classes that Python 2 is still forced to drag around for compatibility, and everything will be fine. The biggest improvement in Python 3 is to finally rid the world of those terrible zombies, old-style classes (in Python 3 your code works fine [[except for the `raise` statement syntax]]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class of object `c` is `type(c)`.

Comment: No. That tells me what class `c` is, but doesn't let me re-instantiate it.

Comment: Yes.  It very much does.  Try it and see.

Comment: @Mark, you said, and I quote, "get the class".  Instantiating it, **of course**, means _calling_ it -- how else do you thing you **ever** instantiate any type or class in Python, except by calling it?!  I notice you had no problem understanding you needed to _call_ the class (or type, same thing) in your comment on @gnibbler's response (which I consider inferior simply because `.__class__` is so much longer than `type()`!), while for me you only had a downvote -- OK, duly noticed.

Comment: @Alex: Don't take so much offense! I *did* try it exactly like Anurag suggested. See my updated question. I down-voted you because I assumed you didn't read past "get the class" and missed the part about "so that I can re-instantiate it". If you did read the question fully, and thought that this would work, or perhaps I'm doing something wrong, then I apologize.

Comment: @gnibbler, true -- one more excellent reason to avoid old-style classes.

Comment: I'd +1 you *now*, but I can't ;)

Answer (score 3):

To get the class of x

```
x.__class__
```